# Create DataSet in Salesforce Analytics using Mule

Tags: salesforce, mule, mulesoft, mule-connector, salesforce-einstein

I'm trying to create a dataset in Salesforce Analytics studio using Mule.
but I'm getting below error,

```
Message               : TRANSACTION: [SaveResult  errors='{[1][Error  extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
fields='{[1]Mode,}'
message='InsightsExternalData: bad field names on insert/update call: Mode'
 statusCode='INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE'
]
,}'
id='null'
success='false'
]
```

Can someone please help me.

**Mule XML:**

```
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:salesforce-analytics="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce-analytics"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce-analytics http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce-analytics/current/mule-salesforce-analytics.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="39742c3b-6115-40d6-a035-9ad8193a59ac" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <salesforce-analytics:salesforce-analytics-config name="Salesforce_Analytics_Config" doc:name="Salesforce Analytics Config" doc:id="da4e917c-ef58-4bdf-9545-c4facb701cec" >
        <salesforce-analytics:basic-connection username="******" password="******" securityToken="*******" url="https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/54.0"/>
    </salesforce-analytics:salesforce-analytics-config>
    <flow name="db-to-crmaFlow" doc:id="822c5892-7459-44d9-8cf0-57a4eea15623" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="ec422115-59a2-4af7-a41c-e7cc11e4f137" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/dbtocrma" allowedMethods="POST"/>
                <salesforce-analytics:create-data-set doc:name="Create data set" doc:id="8a148e00-fb8b-4bb1-b39c-609783d4c9d4" config-ref="Salesforce_Analytics_Config" type="C:\demo\datasetschema.json" operation="UPSERT" description="This is a test dataset to store records coming from database for BR Account" label="datasetschema_csv" dataSetName="datasetschema_csv" target="datasetId"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="46622950-b35a-4c50-a51b-d42f34e2bf67" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

**Dataset Schema File :**

```
{
    "fileFormat": {
        "charsetName": "UTF-8",
        "fieldsDelimitedBy": ",",
        "linesTerminatedBy": "\r\n"
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "connector": "CSV",
            "fullyQualifiedName": "datasetschema_csv",
            "label": "datasetschema_csv",
            "name": "datasetschema_csv",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "Account_Name",
                    "name": "Account_Name",
                    "type": "Text",
                    "label": "Account_Name"


            },
                {
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "Account_ID",
                    "name": "Account_ID",
                    "type": "Numeric",
                    "label": "Account_ID",
                    "precision": 18,
                    "defaultValue": "0",
                    "scale": 0,
                    "format": "0",
                    "decimalSeparator": "",
                    "groupsSeparator": "",
                    "currencySymbol": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using create-data-set connect from Salesforce Analytics module.
And passing a JSON schema in the "type" parameter inside create-data-set connector.

Comment: Don't say MuleSoft instead of Mule. MuleSoft is a company, Mule is one of its products.

Comment: @aled thanks for correcting the mistake, but i was hoping that you'll provide a solution to my problem as well because that's what's more important thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch analytic connector to 3.10.2 as from 3.11+ added new field : Mode.
SFDC wsdl has no Mode field defined. The connector calling SFDC WS behind screen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Todd I'm able to create the dataset and insert the records into it but when I'm trying to insert some more records into the dataset, I'm getting the below error:

Comment: @todd 
Message: TRANSACTION: [SaveResult  errors='{[1][Error  extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
fields='{[0]}'
**message='No more edits'
statusCode='FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION'**
]
,}
id='null'
success='false'
]
Element: db-to-crmFlow/processors/0/route/1/processors/1 @ db-to-crm-with-pagination-30-05:db-to-crm.xml:169 (Upload external data)
Element DSL: <salesforce-analytics:upload-external-data doc:name="Upload external data" doc:id="********" config-ref="Salesforce_Analytics_Config" dataSetId=***></salesforce-analytics:upload-external-data>
Error type: SALESFORCE-ANALYTICS:TRANSACTION

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 'No more edits' error message - it's possible that you reached External Data API limits https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_limits.htm

I also got that message in case, after creating the dataset with salesforce-analytics:create-data-set, I use salesforce-analytics:upload-external-data. If you need to add data into an existing dataset use the Append operation of salesforce-analytics:create-data-set. Each request will add records into the dataset.